# Stop Jackson from reading embedded partial JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

In my program I'm using Netty and a Multicast socket to receive some Multicast packets. I'm wrapping and splitting the actual large data up so the process looks something like this. (Abbreviated class)

```
class Packet {
  private long id;
  private int seq;
  private int max_seq;
  private byte[] data;
}
```

Inside `data` is another JSON string. So I collect the packets and then piece the full JSON back together. The problem is that I'm also serializing the `Packet` into JSON using Jackson and then deserializing.

The problem I've been running into is that I think Jackson is trying to deserialize the `data` as well. The reason is because I'm taking the byte[] data right off the datagram packet and feeding it into the object mapper.

The error I've been getting is:
`org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "@type" (Class pctelelog.Packet), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: [B@36254f63; line: 1, column: 43] (through reference chain: pctelelog.Packet["@type"])`

The data is a serialized class with a number of types already set for correct deserialization so that's why I think Jackson is having issues.

Is there a way to tell Jackson to treat `data` as just byte[] and not try to deserialize it with the rest of the packet?

Comment: I don't see how Jackson can deseiralize the data array into an object. Where the @type property comes from?

Comment: The data contains serialized events which have a SubType defined in their main abstract class. Looks like: @JsonSubTypes({@Type(name = "ClientConnect", value = ClientConnectEvent.class),...}

Comment: the error message says that the json for Packet class does not have the type information. Does seem that there is anything wrong with data field.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@JsonIgnore` on the getter method if you have it, and add `@JsonProperty(name = "data")` on the `byte[] data` property as a setter method:

```
@JsonProperty(name = "data")
private byte[] getData() {
    // get data
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests the problem is not with the `data` field.

It looks like while serializing you are including type information for the `Packet` class (perhaps using `@JsonTypeInfo` for example) as a property `@type` but the deserialization is not handling the `@type` property correctly.

See http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization for more information.